Remove the `length` property from a callable type
Assume I have the following type:
export type Foo<T> = (() => T)

Is it possible to remove the length property from it while keep it callable ?
Also, using Omit, Omit<(() => T), 'length'> prevents it from being callable.


All Javascript functions have a length property corresponding to their arity 2. Typescript is just Javascript, so no you can't change how Javascript works via type annotations 3. Why do you even want to do that?


I join the question: what's the rationale behind omitting length from the function type?

I removed additional properties on the type alias. I'm not looking to modify the function type. I just have a callable object where I'd like to remove the possibility of accessing length.

@MatthieuRiegler let me try a different tack: you are trying to get the compiler to verify something that is definitionally not correct for the language it is compiling. It knows that's a legal runtime access, and that is an invariant of every function type, again by definition. Aside from the irrationality of attacking this particular windmill, again, why do you want to do that? Because the answer is no, you can't do that, or if (as I suspect) this is an XY problem, we may be able to help you.

Foo acts like a wrapper that returns its value when invoked. When the wrapped value is an array, foo.length might be mistaken for foo().length and I'm looking to prevent that.

...but the type system already distinguishes between function types and array types? What case are you envisioning where that happens and the compiler doesn't catch it for other reasons? For instance, if you were looping over the length in a C-style for (x;y;z) loop as soon as you did foo[i] you'd get a type error. Do you have a test case that shows a real problem here or are you speculating?

You cannot really do this in TS (callables have length, by definition). As a workaround you could intersect with {length: never} so that any use of length will probably be suspect, as shown in this playground link.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@JaredSmith if(foo.length) is my main issue.

The snippet if(foo.length) doesn't explain why you would need to care if a function has a length property. I believe this is an an XY Problem. So what's the real problem that makes you think that removing length from a function's type is the solution?

if(foo.length) has no meaning in my context while if(foo().length) has. I just want the typing to prevent any misuses. Believe me, this is not an XY problem. I know what I'm asking for.

Sounds like you want a linter rule to forbid use of function length property (the type isn't the issue, really). You can't do this in TS without forking es5.lib and removing length from Function, but I wouldn't recommend that. The closest I can get to the behavior you want in the type system is the awful lie at this playground link. Does this fully address the question as asked? Or am I missing something about what's happening?

@jcalz Thanks this is what I was looking for, please make it an answer.

You can't really do this. All callables in TypeScript inherit from the Function interface, which is defined in the TypeScript es5.d.ts library to have a numeric length property.  Anything you do that results in a callable type will have that length property present.
The only way to change that would be to fork es5.d.ts locally and remove it, but this would probably break a lot of things and be difficult to maintain.  Probably the "correct" approach would be to make a custom linter rule so that use of function length warns you that it might be a mistake. Within TypeScript itself, though, you don't have too many options.
You can't widen a function to something without length and still have it callable, but you can narrow a function to something whose length is weird/unusable.  The standard approach is to narrow to the never type which is a universal subtype and therefore you can always narrow to it:
type Foo<T> = (() => T) & { length: never };    
declare const f: Foo<string>;
f().length.toFixed(); // okay
f.length.toFixed(); // error

But that won't stop you from checking f.length for truthiness, since even never is allowed there.  TypeScript complains about very little when it comes to truthiness checks; indeed the only thing I've found is when you check a function but don't call it. So we can do the crazy things of telling TypeScript that the length property is both number and some function:
type Foo<T> = (() => T) & { length(x: never): never };
declare const f: Foo<string>;
f().length.toFixed(); // okay
f.length.toFixed(); // error
if (f.length) { // error but for a crazy reason
    console.log(1)
}

But that really is a vile lie; the error says that you meant to call f.length and indeed you can sort of do that (although I made it harder by giving it a never parameter):
f.length(null!) // no error, what?

So I'd say this isn't really the sort of thing TypeScript can do for you well.
Playground link to code
